# inAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, runtime-error, polynomials

I wrote a python program but I got below error

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy 
import io
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from google.colab import files
iodf2 = files.upload()
df=pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(iodf2['BTC-USDD.csv']))
df.dropna(inplace=True) 
df = df[df.iloc[:,0] > 0]
df.iloc[:,0] =numpy.array(df.iloc[:,0], dtype=numpy.int64)
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1],test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
model=numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(xtrain,ytrain,400))
p=model(xtest)
score=r2_score(p,ytest)
print(f'Accuracy for degree 100 is {score}  ')
```

Error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> ValueError: On entry to DLASCL parameter number 4 had an illegal value
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in <cell line: 18>()
> 16 #for degree in range(0,400):
> 17
> ---> 18 model=numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(xtrain,ytrain,400))
> 19 p=model(xtest)
> 20 score=r2_score(p,ytest)
>
> 4 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in
> _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag)
> 98
> 99 def _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag):
> --> 100     raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
> 101
> 102 def _raise_linalgerror_qr(err, flag):
>
> SystemError: <class 'numpy.linalg.LinAlgError'> returned a result with
> an exception set

file BTC-USDD.csv:

Date, Close
20140919,394
20140920,408
20140921,398
20140922,402
20140923,435
20140924,423
20140925,411
20140926,404
20140927,399
20140928,377
20140929,375
20140930,386
20141001,383
20141002,375
20141003,359
20141004,328
20141005,320
20141006,330
20141007,336
20141008,352
20141009,365
20141010,361
20141011,362
20141012,378
20141013,390
20141014,400
20141015,394
20141016,382
20141017,383
20141018,391
20141019,389
20141020,382
20141021,386
20141022,383
20141023,358
20141024,358
20141025,347
20141026,354
20141027,352
20141028,357
20141029,335
20141030,345
20141031,338
20141101,325
20141102,325
20141103,327
20141104,330
20141105,339
20141106,349
20141107,342
20141108,345
20141109,363
20141110,366
20141111,367
20141112,423
20141113,420
20141114,397
20141115,376
20141116,387
20141117,387
20141118,375
20141119,380
20141120,357
20141121,350
20141122,352
20141123,367
20141124,376
20141125,375
20141126,368
20141127,369
20141128,376
20141129,375
20141130,378
20141201,379
20141202,381
20141203,375
20141204,369
20141205,376
20141206,374
20141207,375
20141208,361
20141209,352
20141210,346
20141211,350
20141212,352
20141213,347
20141214,351
20141215,345
20141216,327
20141217,319
20141218,311
20141219,317
20141220,329
20141221,320
20141222,331
20141223,334
20141224,322
20141225,319
20141226,327
20141227,315
20141228,317
20141229,312
20141230,310
20141231,320
20150101,314
20150102,315
20150103,281
20150104,264
20150105,274
20150106,286
20150107,294
20150108,283
20150109,290
20150110,274
20150111,265
20150112,267
20150113,225
20150114,178
20150115,209
20150116,208
20150117,199
20150118,210
20150119,214
20150120,211
20150121,226
20150122,233
20150123,232
20150124,247
20150125,253
20150126,273
20150127,263
20150128,233
20150129,233
20150130,226
20150131,217
20150201,226
20150202,238
20150203,227
20150204,226
20150205,217
20150206,222
20150207,227
20150208,223
20150209,220
20150210,219
20150211,219
20150212,221
20150213,235
20150214,257
20150215,234
20150216,233
20150217,243
20150218,236
20150219,240
20150220,243
20150221,244
20150222,235
20150223,238
20150224,238
20150225,237
20150226,236
20150227,253
20150228,254
20150301,260
20150302,275
20150303,281
20150304,273
20150305,276
20150306,272
20150307,276
20150308,274
20150309,289
20150310,291
20150311,296
20150312,294
20150313,285
20150314,281
20150315,286
20150316,290
20150317,285
20150318,256
20150319,260
20150320,261
20150321,260
20150322,267
20150323,266
20150324,245
20150325,246
20150326,248
20150327,247
20150328,252
20150329,242
20150330,247
20150331,244
20150401,247
20150402,253
20150403,254
20150404,253
20150405,260
20150406,255
20150407,253
20150408,245
20150409,243
20150410,236
20150411,236
20150412,236
20150413,224
20150414,219
20150415,223
20150416,228
20150417,222
20150418,223
20150419,222
20150420,224
20150421,235
20150422,234
20150423,236
20150424,231
20150425,226
20150426,219
20150427,229
20150428,225
20150429,225
20150430,236
20150501,232
20150502,234
20150503,240
20150504,239
20150505,236
20150506,229
20150507,237
20150508,243
20150509,241
20150510,240
20150511,242
20150512,241
20150513,236
20150514,236
20150515,237
20150516,236
20150517,236
20150518,233
20150519,231
20150520,234
20150521,235
20150522,240
20150523,238
20150524,240
20150525,237
20150526,237
20150527,237
20150528,237
20150529,237
20150530,233
20150531,230
20150601,222
20150602,225
20150603,225
20150604,224
20150605,224
20150606,225
20150607,222
20150608,228
20150609,229
20150610,228
20150611,229
20150612,229
20150613,232
20150614,233
20150615,236
20150616,250
20150617,249
20150618,249
20150619,244
20150620,245
20150621,243
20150622,246
20150623,244
20150624,240
20150625,242
20150626,243
20150627,250
20150628,249
20150629,257
20150630,263
20150701,258
20150702,255
20150703,256
20150704,260
20150705,271
20150706,269
20150707,266
20150708,270
20150709,269
20150710,284
20150711,293
20150712,310
20150713,292
20150714,287
20150715,285
20150716,278
20150717,279
20150718,274
20150719,273
20150720,278
20150721,275
20150722,277
20150723,276
20150724,288
20150725,288
20150726,292
20150727,293
20150728,294
20150729,289
20150730,287
20150731,284
20150801,281
20150802,282
20150803,281
20150804,285
20150805,281
20150806,278
20150807,279
20150808,260
20150809,265
20150810,264
20150811,270
20150812,266
20150813,264
20150814,265
20150815,261
20150816,258
20150817,257
20150818,211
20150819,226
20150820,235
20150821,232
20150822,230
20150823,228
20150824,210
20150825,221
20150826,225
20150827,224
20150828,231
20150829,229
20150830,228
20150831,230
20150901,228
20150902,229
20150903,227
20150904,230
20150905,235
20150906,239
20150907,239
20150908,243
20150909,238
20150910,238
20150911,240
20150912,235
20150913,230
20150914,230
20150915,230
20150916,229
20150917,229
20150918,232
20150919,231
20150920,231
20150921,227
20150922,230
20150923,230
20150924,234
20150925,235
20150926,234
20150927,232
20150928,239
20150929,236
20150930,236
20151001,237
20151002,237
20151003,238
20151004,238
20151005,240
20151006,246
20151007,242
20151008,242
20151009,243
20151010,244
20151011,247
20151012,245
20151013,249
20151014,251
20151015,254
20151016,262
20151017,270
20151018,261
20151019,263
20151020,269
20151021,266
20151022,274
20151023,276
20151024,281
20151025,283
20151026,285
20151027,293
20151028,304
20151029,313
20151030,328
20151031,314
20151101,325
20151102,361
20151103,403
20151104,411
20151105,386
20151106,374
20151107,386
20151108,373
20151109,380
20151110,336
20151111,311
20151112,338
20151113,336
20151114,332
20151115,320
20151116,330
20151117,335
20151118,334
20151119,326
20151120,322
20151121,326
20151122,324
20151123,323
20151124,320
20151125,328
20151126,352
20151127,358
20151128,357
20151129,371
20151130,377
20151201,362
20151202,359
20151203,361
20151204,363
20151205,388
20151206,388
20151207,395
20151208,415
20151209,417
20151210,415
20151211,451
20151212,434
20151213,433
20151214,444
20151215,465
20151216,454
20151217,456
20151218,463
20151219,462
20151220,442
20151221,438
20151222,436
20151223,442
20151224,454
20151225,455
20151226,417
20151227,422
20151228,422
20151229,432
20151230,426
20151231,430
20160101,434
20160102,433
20160103,430
20160104,433
20160105,431
20160106,429
20160107,458
20160108,453
20160109,447
20160110,447
20160111,448
20160112,435
20160113,432
20160114,430
20160115,364
20160116,387
20160117,382
20160118,387
20160119,380
20160120,420
20160121,410
20160122,382
20160123,387
20160124,402
20160125,391
20160126,392
20160127,394
20160128,380
20160129,379
20160130,378
20160131,368
20160201,373
20160202,374
20160203,369
20160204,389
20160205,386
20160206,376
20160207,376
20160208,373
20160209,376
20160210,381
20160211,379
20160212,384
20160213,391
20160214,407
20160215,400
20160216,407
20160217,416
20160218,422
20160219,420
20160220,437
20160221,438
20160222,437
20160223,420
20160224,424
20160225,424
20160226,432
20160227,432
20160228,433
20160229,437
20160301,435
20160302,423
20160303,421
20160304,410
20160305,400
20160306,407
20160307,414
20160308,413
20160309,414
20160310,417
20160311,421
20160312,411
20160313,414
20160314,416
20160315,416
20160316,417
20160317,420
20160318,409
20160319,410
20160320,413
20160321,413
20160322,418
20160323,418
20160324,416
20160325,417
20160326,417
20160327,426
20160328,424
20160329,416
20160330,414
20160331,416
20160401,417
20160402,420
20160403,420
20160404,421
20160405,424
20160406,423
20160407,422
20160408,420
20160409,419
20160410,421
20160411,422
20160412,425
20160413,423
20160414,424
20160415,429
20160416,430
20160417,427
20160418,428
20160419,435
20160420,441
20160421,449
20160422,445
20160423,450
20160424,458
20160425,461
20160426,466
20160427,444
20160428,449
20160429,455
20160430,448
20160501,451
20160502,444
20160503,450
20160504,446
20160505,447
20160506,459
20160507,458
20160508,458
20160509,460
20160510,450
20160511,452
20160512,454
20160513,455
20160514,455
20160515,457
20160516,454
20160517,453
20160518,454
20160519,438
20160520,442
20160521,443
20160522,439
20160523,444
20160524,445
20160525,449
20160526,453
20160527,473
20160528,530
20160529,526
20160530,533
20160531,531
20160601,536
20160602,537
20160603,569
20160604,572
20160605,574
20160606,585
20160607,576
20160608,581
20160609,574
20160610,577
20160611,606
20160612,672
20160613,704
20160614,685
20160615,694
20160616,766
20160617,748
20160618,756
20160619,763
20160620,737
20160621,666
20160622,596
20160623,623
20160624,665
20160625,665
20160626,629
20160627,655
20160628,647
20160629,639
20160630,673
20160701,676
20160702,703
20160703,658
20160704,683
20160705,670
20160706,677
20160707,640
20160708,666
20160709,650
20160710,649
20160711,647
20160712,664
20160713,654
20160714,658
20160715,663
20160716,660
20160717,679
20160718,673
20160719,672
20160720,665
20160721,665
20160722,650
20160723,655
20160724,661
20160725,654
20160726,651
20160727,654
20160728,655
20160729,656
20160730,655
20160731,624
20160801,606
20160802,547
20160803,566
20160804,578
20160805,575
20160806,587
20160807,592
20160808,591
20160809,587
20160810,592
20160811,589
20160812,587
20160813,585
20160814,570
20160815,567
20160816,577
20160817,573
20160818,574
20160819,575
20160820,581
20160821,581
20160822,586
20160823,583
20160824,580
20160825,577
20160826,579
20160827,569
20160828,573
20160829,574
20160830,577
20160831,575
20160901,572
20160902,575
20160903,598
20160904,608
20160905,606
20160906,610
20160907,614
20160908,626
20160909,622
20160910,623
20160911,606
20160912,608
20160913,609
20160914,610
20160915,607
20160916,606
20160917,605
20160918,609
20160919,609
20160920,608
20160921,597
20160922,596
20160923,602
20160924,602
20160925,600
20160926,608
20160927,606
20160928,604
20160929,605
20160930,609
20161001,613
20161002,610
20161003,612
20161004,610
20161005,612
20161006,613
20161007,617
20161008,619
20161009,616
20161010,618
20161011,641
20161012,636
20161013,636
20161014,640
20161015,638
20161016,641
20161017,639
20161018,637
20161019,630
20161020,630
20161021,632
20161022,657
20161023,657
20161024,653
20161025,657
20161026,678
20161027,688
20161028,689
20161029,714
20161030,701
20161031,700
20161101,729
20161102,740
20161103,688
20161104,703
20161105,703
20161106,711
20161107,703
20161108,709
20161109,723
20161110,715
20161111,716
20161112,705
20161113,702
20161114,705
20161115,711
20161116,744
20161117,740
20161118,751
20161119,751
20161120,731
20161121,739
20161122,751
20161123,744
20161124,740
20161125,741
20161126,735
20161127,732
20161128,735
20161129,735
20161130,745
20161201,756
20161202,777
20161203,771
20161204,773
20161205,758
20161206,764
20161207,768
20161208,770
20161209,772
20161210,774
20161211,769
20161212,780
20161213,780
20161214,781
20161215,778
20161216,784
20161217,790
20161218,790
20161219,792
20161220,800
20161221,834
20161222,864
20161223,921
20161224,898
20161225,896
20161226,907
20161227,933
20161228,975
20161229,973
20161230,961
20161231,963
20170101,998
20170102,1021
20170103,1043
20170104,1154
20170105,1013
20170106,902
20170107,908
20170108,911
20170109,902
20170110,907
20170111,777
20170112,804
20170113,823
20170114,818
20170115,821
20170116,831
20170117,907
20170118,886
20170119,899
20170120,895
20170121,921
20170122,924
20170123,921
20170124,892
20170125,901
20170126,917
20170127,919
20170128,921
20170129,919
20170130,920
20170131,970
20170201,989
20170202,1011
20170203,1029
20170204,1042
20170205,1027
20170206,1038
20170207,1061
20170208,1063
20170209,994
20170210,988
20170211,1004
20170212,999
20170213,990
20170214,1004
20170215,1007
20170216,1027
20170217,1046
20170218,1054
20170219,1047
20170220,1079
20170221,1115
20170222,1117
20170223,1166
20170224,1173
20170225,1143
20170226,1165
20170227,1179
20170228,1179
20170301,1222
20170302,1251
20170303,1274
20170304,1255
20170305,1267
20170306,1272
20170307,1223
20170308,1150
20170309,1188
20170310,1116
20170311,1175
20170312,1221
20170313,1231
20170314,1240
20170315,1249
20170316,1187
20170317,1100
20170318,973
20170319,1036
20170320,1054
20170321,1120
20170322,1049
20170323,1038
20170324,937
20170325,972
20170326,966
20170327,1045
20170328,1047
20170329,1039
20170330,1026
20170331,1071
20170401,1080
20170402,1102
20170403,1143
20170404,1133
20170405,1124
20170406,1182
20170407,1176
20170408,1175
20170409,1187
20170410,1187
20170411,1205
20170412,1200
20170413,1169
20170414,1167
20170415,1172
20170416,1182
20170417,1193
20170418,1211
20170419,1210
20170420,1229
20170421,1222
20170422,1231
20170423,1207
20170424,1250
20170425,1265
20170426,1281
20170427,1317
20170428,1316
20170429,1321
20170430,1347
20170501,1421
20170502,1452
20170503,1490
20170504,1537
20170505,1555
20170506,1578
20170507,1596
20170508,1723
20170509,1755
20170510,1787
20170511,1848
20170512,1724
20170513,1804
20170514,1808
20170515,1738
20170516,1734
20170517,1839
20170518,1888
20170519,1987
20170520,2084
20170521,2041
20170522,2173
20170523,2320
20170524,2443
20170525,2304
20170526,2202
20170527,2038
20170528,2155
20170529,2255
20170530,2175
20170531,2286
20170601,2407
20170602,2488
20170603,2515
20170604,2511
20170605,2686
20170606,2863
20170607,2732
20170608,2805
20170609,2823
20170610,2947
20170611,2958
20170612,2659
20170613,2717
20170614,2506
20170615,2464
20170616,2518
20170617,2655
20170618,2548
20170619,2589
20170620,2721
20170621,2689
20170622,2705
20170623,2744
20170624,2608
20170625,2589
20170626,2478
20170627,2552
20170628,2574
20170629,2539
20170630,2480
20170701,2434
20170702,2506
20170703,2564
20170704,2601
20170705,2601
20170706,2608
20170707,2518
20170708,2571
20170709,2518
20170710,2372
20170711,2337
20170712,2398
20170713,2357
20170714,2233
20170715,1998
20170716,1929
20170717,2228
20170718,2318
20170719,2273
20170720,2817
20170721,2667
20170722,2810
20170723,2730
20170724,2754
20170725,2576
20170726,2529
20170727,2671
20170728,2809
20170729,2726
20170730,2757
20170731,2875
20170801,2718
20170802,2710
20170803,2804
20170804,2895
20170805,3252
20170806,3213
20170807,3378
20170808,3419
20170809,3342
20170810,3381
20170811,3650
20170812,3884
20170813,4073
20170814,4325
20170815,4181
20170816,4376
20170817,4331
20170818,4160
20170819,4193
20170820,4087
20170821,4001
20170822,4100
20170823,4151
20170824,4334
20170825,4371
20170826,4352
20170827,4382
20170828,4382
20170829,4579
20170830,4565
20170831,4703
20170901,4892
20170902,4578
20170903,4582
20170904,4236
20170905,4376
20170906,4597
20170907,4599
20170908,4228
20170909,4226
20170910,4122
20170911,4161
20170912,4130
20170913,3882
20170914,3154
20170915,3637
20170916,3625
20170917,3582
20170918,4065
20170919,3924
20170920,3905
20170921,3631
20170922,3630
20170923,3792
20170924,3682
20170925,3926
20170926,3892
20170927,4200
20170928,4174
20170929,4163
20170930,4338
20171001,4403
20171002,4409
20171003,4317
20171004,4229
20171005,4328
20171006,4370
20171007,4426
20171008,4610
20171009,4772
20171010,4781
20171011,4826
20171012,5446
20171013,5647
20171014,5831
20171015,5678
20171016,5725
20171017,5605
20171018,5590
20171019,5708
20171020,6011
20171021,6031
20171022,6008
20171023,5930
20171024,5526
20171025,5750
20171026,5904
20171027,5780
20171028,5753
20171029,6153
20171030,6130
20171031,6468
20171101,6767
20171102,7078
20171103,7207
20171104,7379
20171105,7407
20171106,7022
20171107,7144
20171108,7459
20171109,7143
20171110,6618
20171111,6357
20171112,5950
20171113,6559
20171114,6635
20171115,7315
20171116,7871
20171117,7708
20171118,7790
20171119,8036
20171120,8200
20171121,8071
20171122,8253
20171123,8038
20171124,8253
20171125,8790
20171126,9330
20171127,9818
20171128,10058
20171129,9888
20171130,10233
20171201,10975
20171202,11074
20171203,11323
20171204,11657
20171205,11916
20171206,14291
20171207,17899
20171208,16569
20171209,15178
20171210,15455
20171211,16936
20171212,17415
20171213,16408
20171214,16564
20171215,17706
20171216,19497
20171217,19140
20171218,19114
20171219,17776
20171220,16624
20171221,15802
20171222,13831
20171223,14699
20171224,13925
20171225,14026
20171226,16099
20171227,15838
20171228,14606
20171229,14656
20171230,12952
20171231,14156
20180101,13657
20180102,14982
20180103,15201
20180104,15599
20180105,17429
20180106,17527
20180107,16477
20180108,15170
20180109,14595
20180110,14973
20180111,13405
20180112,13980
20180113,14360
20180114,13772
20180115,13819
20180116,11490
20180117,11188
20180118,11474
20180119,11607
20180120,12899
20180121,11600
20180122,10931
20180123,10868
20180124,11359
20180125,11259
20180126,11171
20180127,11440
20180128,11786
20180129,11296
20180130,10106
20180131,10221
20180201,9170
20180202,8830
20180203,9174
20180204,8277
20180205,6955
20180206,7754
20180207,7621
20180208,8265
20180209,8736
20180210,8621
20180211,8129
20180212,8926
20180213,8598
20180214,9494
20180215,10166
20180216,10233
20180217,11112
20180218,10551
20180219,11225
20180220,11403
20180221,10690
20180222,10005
20180223,10301
20180224,9813
20180225,9664
20180226,10366
20180227,10725
20180228,10397
20180301,10951
20180302,11086
20180303,11489
20180304,11512
20180305,11573
20180306,10779
20180307,9965
20180308,9395
20180309,9337
20180310,8866
20180311,9578
20180312,9205
20180313,9194
20180314,8269
20180315,8300
20180316,8338
20180317,7916
20180318,8223
20180319,8630
20180320,8913
20180321,8929
20180322,8728
20180323,8879
20180324,8668
20180325,8495
20180326,8209
20180327,7833
20180328,7954
20180329,7165
20180330,6890
20180331,6973
20180401,6844
20180402,7083
20180403,7456
20180404,6853
20180405,6811
20180406,6636
20180407,6911
20180408,7023
20180409,6770
20180410,6834
20180411,6968
20180412,7889
20180413,7895
20180414,7986
20180415,8329
20180416,8058
20180417,7902
20180418,8163
20180419,8294
20180420,8845
20180421,8895
20180422,8802
20180423,8930
20180424,9697
20180425,8845
20180426,9281
20180427,8987
20180428,9348
20180429,9419
20180430,9240
20180501,9119
20180502,9235
20180503,9743
20180504,9700
20180505,9858
20180506,9654
20180507,9373
20180508,9234
20180509,9325
20180510,9043
20180511,8441

what is the problem????

Answer (score 0):

> SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

This error is usually caused by **NaN's** or **infinity** in your `.csv` file.

You can try to use method `pd.notnull` and `np.isfinite` to check it if there is a lot of data in your `.csv` file.

Comment: please check my code again

Comment: As I said, you have to check your `BTC-USD.csv`.

Comment: I got BTC-USD.csv from yahoo finance.I think it is ok. and I try above code in google colab but I got above error     . csv file is below                                                   Date,    Open,         High,        Low,      Close,   Adj Close,Volume
20140919,424.102997,427.834991,384.532013,394.795990,394.795990,37919700
20140920,394.673004,423.295990,389.882996,408.903992,408.903992,36863600

Comment: this error raised because of this code ==>"model=numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(xtrain,ytrain,degree))"

Comment: I sent you csv file . please check it